# How to check if a checkbox is checked in pyqt

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4

I'm trying to make a conditional statement based on whether a checkbox is checked or not. I've tried something like the following, but it always returns as true.

```
self.folderactive = QtGui.QCheckBox(self.folders)
self.folderactive.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 390, 71, 21))
self.folderactive.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("folderactive"))
if self.folderactive.isChecked:
    folders.createDir('Desktop')
    print "pass"
elif not self.folderactive.isChecked:
    folders.deleteDir('Desktop')
    print "nopass"
```

Is there a way to get a bool value of whether a checkbox is checked or not?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

`self.folderactive.isChecked` isn't a boolean, it's a method - which, in a boolean context, will always evaluate to `True`. If you want the state of the checkbox, just invoke the method:

```
if self.folderactive.isChecked():
    ...
else:
    ...
```

Comment: to avoid the if-then-else construct and keep track of the state myself, programatically, is there anything that emits a signal when a checkBox is checked (another when unchecked), like ```        self.checkBox.toggled.connect(self.calculate)``` ?

Comment: @Echeban Did you find out if there is such a thing, I was looking for it

Comment: here --> -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59437747/checkbox-to-a-variables-pyqt5

Answer (score 4):

```
x = self.folderactive.isChecked()
```

`x` will be `True` or `False`—a Boolean value.

(It's the brackets at the end that make the difference.)

Comment: but wont be dinamically updated in a script, or would it ??

Comment: It won't be. Should use .itemChanged for events